# OpenCL half4 type Apple OS X

Tags: macos, opencl

Does anybody know the state of half precision floating point support in OpenCL as implemented by Apple.

According to http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_fp16.html

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp16 : enable
```

should enable support for types such as half4 but when I come to build the kernel the compiler throws a message such as

```
error: variable has incomplete type 'half4' (aka 'struct __Reserved_Name__Do_not_use_half4')
```

is there anyway I can have half4 support in Apple's OpenCL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cl_khr_fp16 extension (floating point operations on the 16bit scalar type (half) and vectors of half (half2,half3,half4,half8,half16) is an *optional* extension to OpenCL 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2.

An OpenCL extension defines a macro of the same name as the extension if it is supported in the OpenCL implementation.

e.g.

```
#ifdef cl_khr_fp16
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp16 : enable
... // Code using half
#else
#error No FP16 support
#endif
```

I do not believe Apple are shipping an OpenCL with half support.

Answer (score 1):

The latest shipping Apple implementation is on Lion, and it supports OpenCL 1.1.  You are looking at the recently released OpenCL 1.2 *specification*.  That simply documents what will be in a given 1.2 implementation of OpenCL, whoever the vendor might be.

Comment: cl_khr_fp16 is supported in OpenCL 1.0 too. I just gave the 1.2 page as it has a little more detail. http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_fp16.html